# Converting _bstr_t to float in C++

Tags: c++, bstr-t

I need to convert a _bstr_t that comes from the DB (ADO) to float, have a look at the code segment:

```
_bstr_t valueDB = productsDB->Fields->GetItem("Value")->Value;
float referenceFloatValue = productsDB->Fields->GetItem("Value")->Value.fltVal;
```

I'm trying to use .fltVal, but it's not working (before the instruction the value of referenceFloatValue's 0.0, (different value of valueDB). Does anybody know what I need to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`wcstod(valueDB);`
but you have to sanitize the string before ( ensure it is not null, ensure it is written in properly format ) otherwise you get in troubles.
Maybe is not up to you, but in general is better if a field has to represent a number, to be defined to contain a number.
Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab.aspx